# Wordpress wp_get_attachment_image doesn't show images for every post

Tags: php, wordpress

wp_get_attachment_image() gets images only for 2 out of 5 posts.

I am new to WordPress, I am making theme where main page only shows images (attachments) from posts. Posts are all in the same manner - title, paragraph, and gallery. Each of them have category assigned to it.
Tried to fix the problem in many ways but none seem to be working. I've dumped every post and it seems that

```
$postyMarkiQq = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'marki' ) );
$posty = $postyMarkiQq->posts;
```

gets information properly.
I've tried using `get_attached_media('', $post->ID)` but it returns same results.
I've tried putting the main part of the code to function.

```
<?php
    $postyBrandQ = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'brand' ) );
    $posty = $postyBrandQ->posts;

    foreach($posty as $post) {
        echo $post->ID;
    ?>

    <div class="category">
        <?php
            echo get_the_title( $post->ID );
            $args = array(
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
            );
            $attachments = get_children( $args );
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID);
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I don't have any idea why wouldn't this work.
Would really appreciate help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be querying by post parent. Attachments are only given post parents based on the page you are currently viewing when you upload the item to the media library. If you click media, and upload images, the images won't have a post parent, even if you go to a post (or page) later on, and set that image as the featured image.

So, I don't know the exact context of your question, but perhaps get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) will be the answer you are looking for. This will return the attachment ID of the featured image, then you can use wp_get_attachment_image_src() (pass in the attachment ID probably), which will return you an array. Print the array, in there somewhere you will find the URL.

Comment: In addition, if you just want to loop through posts, use get_posts() instead of new WP_Query(), passing in the same array of arguments. get_posts() will return you an array. Although it works to access $query->posts (where $query is an instance of WP_Query), its not quite the right way to do it and some things won't work properly. When you use WP_Query objects you normally want to do things in a particular way, checking $query->have_posts() and $query->the_post() and whatnot. Sorry I don't feel like explaining better but there's lots of documentation online for this.

Comment: Lastly, if you did have a reason to query for attachments, which perhaps you don't here, you probably don't have to pass in the post_mime_type argument unless you know what that does and are sure that you want it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, and for some tips regarding Wordpress. Sadly, your  answer doesn't help with my problem. Wordpress isn't made for what I am trying to do with it. Rethinking the strategy at the moment. :)

Comment: I'm going to guess from your brief description that it is possible, if you explain more, maybe someone will give you a better answer.